# set vim colorscheme based on putty session

Tags: vim, putty, gnu-screen

How would I cause vim to startup with a different color scheme depending on whether or not I was connected via a PuTTY ssh session? I have a preferred color scheme that doesn't display correctly through putty, but I need to use putty sometimes when I'm connecting via public terminals.

Does PuTTY set any environment variables?

Comment: I don't think so. What does the documentation say on that mattter?

Comment: Are you using the default color scheme that comes with PuTTY?  If so consider switching to something like [Pretty PuTTY](https://github.com/jacktrocinski/pretty-putty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puty seems to be able to set environment variables via Configuration->connection->data.

After that, you could do, in the `.vimrc`:

```
if !empty($VARIABLE_PUTTY)
    colorscheme my_putty_color_scheme
else
    colorscheme my_default_color_scheme
endif
```

Comment: That would still require typing something in, but I'll accept the answer. Guess I'll just find a color scheme that works well enough for both.

Comment: *Configuration -> Data -> Terminal-type string* sets the `TERM` variable when connecting.  I recommend setting this value to `putty-256color` to have 256 color support.